# Why if the id = '0' in "InlineQueryResultArticle" the element chosen doesn't trigger the "on_chosen_inline_result" code?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm new to Python and new to Stack Overflow, sorry for my mistakes...

I'm using Telepot to write a bot for Telegram.
When dealing with inline results I can only make the code in `on_chosen_inline_result` execute for every article I choose other than the first created.

```
def on_inline_query(msg):
    query_id, from_id, query_string = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='inline_query')
    tastiera_inline = InlineKeyboardMarkup(*some_keyboard*)

    articles = []

    if query_string:

        found_conte = fun.get_conta(titolo=query_string)
        if found_conte == 1:
            return
        for conta_inline in found_conte:
            articles.append(InlineQueryResultArticle(
                id=str(conta_inline['id']),
                title=conta_inline['titolo'],
                input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(*some_content*),
                reply_markup=tastiera_inline,
                description=conta_inline['testo'],
                thumb_url=*some_url*,
            ))

    else:
        if fun.get_conta('all') == 1:
            return
        for conta_inline in fun.get_conta('all'):
            articles.append(InlineQueryResultArticle(
                id=str(conta_inline['id']),
                title=conta_inline['titolo'],
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(*some_content*),
            reply_markup=tastiera_inline,
            description=conta_inline['testo'],
            thumb_url=*some_url*,
        ))

     bot.answerInlineQuery(query_id, articles)


def on_chosen_inline_result(msg):  

    print(msg)


bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)

bot.message_loop({'chat': on_chat_message,
              'inline_query': on_inline_query,
              'chosen_inline_result': on_chosen_inline_result
              },
             run_forever='Listening ...')
```

`print(msg)` is working fine for every article I choose from the list of answers to the inline query except for the first one created.
I am really confused...

What is really confusing is that I don't think to have the control on what happens when I choose an article from the list in Telegram, so it seems strange that sometimes it triggers the `on_chosen_inline_result` code and other times it doesn't.

EDIT: It seems like if `id='0'` in `InlineQueryResultArticle` the chosen result doesn't trigger the code inside `on_chosen_inline_result`, but I'm not 100% sure this is the cause, and I really don't know why, anyway...

PS: I don't know how much code is needed to understand the problem without copying everything here. I can surely edit the question and add more code if needed.

Comment: What does the word "catch" mean in  _I can only catch `chosen_inline_result` if ..._?

Comment: I mean that the code in `on_chosen_inline_result` only executes if I have more than one object in the db used to generate the articles.

Comment: The code for `on_chosen_inline_result()` is very simple so I don't think the problem is there.  I did notice a possible issue in `on_inline_query()` -- it doesn't always return a list of articles.  If `get_conta()` returns 1 then it does return the article list, but otherwise it doesn't return anything at all, and therefore returns `None` by default.

Comment: `return articles` was there for another reason, my mistake, but the code itself doesn't need to return something, the code just build the `articles` list, then `bot.answerInlineQuery(query_id, articles)` gets that list and create the answers.

Comment: I'm trying to debug it. I started this part of code ( `on_inline_query` and `on_chosen_inline_result` ) from scratch again, and I think it's something about the `id=`, because if I change that value sometimes the code inside `on_chosen_inline_result` execute, sometimes it doesn't, but I still can't understand why...

Comment: It seems like if `id='0'` the result doesn't trigger the `on_chosen_inline_result` . Is it possible? And if it is, why?

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `conta_inline['id']` (or logging it to a file) so that you can see exactly what the value is, instead of trying to guess what it might be?

Comment: I've tried to hard-code `id='0'` and the code in `on_chosen_inline_result` doesn't execute, while with every other value it does execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own test, it seems your suspicion is correct. I have tried a variety of id strings and chosen each of them in turn:

- `00` → Yes (`chosen_inline_result` gotten)
- `$0` → Yes
- `0` → No
- `1` → Yes

As the author of telepot, I can't think of anywhere a result id of `0` may get filtered out inadvertently. So I am presuming it's a Telegram issue.

As illustrated above, it's easy to get around. You can prepend almost any character in front to get back the `chosen_inline_result`.

In case anyone is interested, here's my testing code:

```
import sys
import threading
import telepot
from telepot.namedtuple import InlineQueryResultArticle, InputTextMessageContent

def on_inline_query(msg):
    def compute():
        query_id, from_id, query_string = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='inline_query')
        print('%s: Computing for: %s' % (threading.current_thread().name, query_string))

        articles = [InlineQueryResultArticle(
                        id='00', title='ID=00',
                        input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                            message_text='ID=00')),
                    InlineQueryResultArticle(
                        id='$0', title='ID=$0',
                        input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                            message_text='ID=$0')),
                    InlineQueryResultArticle(
                        id='0', title='ID=0',
                        input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                            message_text='ID=0')),
                    InlineQueryResultArticle(
                        id='1', title='ID=1',
                        input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                            message_text='ID=1')),]

        return dict(results=articles)

    answerer.answer(msg, compute)

def on_chosen_inline_result(msg):
    result_id, from_id, query_string = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='chosen_inline_result')
    print('Chosen Inline Result:', result_id, from_id, query_string)

TOKEN = sys.argv[1]  # get token from command-line

bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
answerer = telepot.helper.Answerer(bot)

bot.message_loop({'inline_query': on_inline_query,
                  'chosen_inline_result': on_chosen_inline_result},
                 run_forever='Listening ...')
```

Comment: Simply starting the IDs from '1' instead of '0' also does the job. Thank you very much.